# binding background to resources file

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have some `window` and I want to bind it's background to file that is located under `Resources\DBSelection.jpg`

How i can do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <Window.Background >
         <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources\DBSelection.jpg" > </ImageBrush >
    </Window.Background >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not bind to files, you can only bind to public properties/dependency properties. So if you need a binding you could pipe the image through a property in your code. You also would need something like a `FileSystemWatcher` so you can send a notification that the file changed.